# How execute function after append with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute a function right after i append a HTML element i've try a lot of things and nothing works, here is the source

```
$(doc).find("#"+parent.substring(1)).append(childStr)
$('[load]').each(function() {
    $(this).load(function(){
        loadmdl($(this).attr('id'));
    })
});
```

I know here are a lot of question similars but the answers of that questions doesn't help me. I really need an advice. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure your selector is wrong. 'load' is not really a valid html attribute.

Comment: Is not? Ok, but still i just used the attribute to collect the function that i going to execute after append the element but always execute the function before append the element.

Comment: It shouldn't. Try a .load class and iterating through that. Check if if your selector returns any elements at all, too.

Comment: Yes, return because the function collects correctly the strings that i going to execute.

Comment: I' ve change the name the attribute to 'loadafter', and still it's making the same thing executes the code before append the element.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not working in the way you think it's not working? Calling additional JavaScript code after an `.append` is perfectly normal.

Are you sure the `$('[load]')` selector is returning what you want it to?

Comment: Yes i am sure because after that the function collect all the source attributes and execute the eval function with them as an arguments but always execute the function before append the element not after.